# add subtotal column by condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

could you please advice how to add Quater column, contains sum of months values

| part | 2024-03-01 00:00:00 | 2024-04-01 00:00:00 | 2024-05-01 00:00:00 | 2024-06-01 00:00:00 | 2024-07-01 00:00:00 | 2024-08-01 00:00:00 | 2024-09-01 00:00:00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| part1 | 6 | 8 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 5 | 5 |
| part2 | 7 | 1 | 3 | 8 | 9 | 4 | 10 |
| part3 | 10 | 7 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 10 | 0 |
| part4 | 6 | 9 | 3 | 0 | 10 | 9 | 10 |
| part5 | 2 | 1 | 10 | 8 | 7 | 3 | 3 |
| part6 | 1 | 0 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 7 | 8 |

I'm tring to get output like this:

| part | 2024-03-01 00:00:00 | Q1'24 | 2024-04-01 00:00:00 | 2024-05-01 00:00:00 | 2024-06-01 00:00:00 | Q2'24 | 2024-07-01 00:00:00 | 2024-08-01 00:00:00 | 2024-09-01 00:00:00 | Q3'24 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| part1 | 6 | 6 | 8 | 2 | 3 | 13 | 0 | 5 | 5 | 10 |
| part2 | 7 | 7 | 1 | 3 | 8 | 12 | 9 | 4 | 10 | 23 |
| part3 | 10 | 10 | 7 | 4 | 5 | 16 | 6 | 10 | 0 | 16 |
| part4 | 6 | 6 | 9 | 3 | 0 | 12 | 10 | 9 | 10 | 29 |
| part5 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 10 | 8 | 19 | 7 | 3 | 3 | 13 |
| part6 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 7 | 8 | 16 |

[raw data](https://www.transfernow.net/dl/202403183F2yz2xd)

Comment: Can u add sample raw data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert columns to quarter periods by [`DatetimeIndex.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html) for subtotals, join to original by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and for correct order add [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
out = (pd.concat([df,
                 df.groupby(df.columns.to_period('Q'), axis=1).sum()],
                 axis=1)
         .sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: pd.PeriodIndex(x, 'Q')))


out.columns = [x.strftime("Q%q'%y") if isinstance(x, pd.Period) 
               else x for x in out.columns]
```

---

```
print (out)
       2024-03-01 00:00:00  Q1'24  2024-04-01 00:00:00  2024-05-01 00:00:00  \
part                                                                          
part1                    6      6                    8                    2   
part2                    7      7                    1                    3   
part3                   10     10                    7                    4   
part4                    6      6                    9                    3   
part5                    2      2                    1                   10   
part6                    1      1                    0                    4   

       2024-06-01 00:00:00  Q2'24  2024-07-01 00:00:00  2024-08-01 00:00:00  \
part                                                                          
part1                    3     13                    0                    5   
part2                    8     12                    9                    4   
part3                    5     16                    6                   10   
part4                    0     12                   10                    9   
part5                    8     19                    7                    3   
part6                    1      5                    1                    7   

       2024-09-01 00:00:00  Q3'24  
part                               
part1                    5     10  
part2                   10     23  
part3                    0     16  
part4                   10     29  
part5                    3     13  
part6                    8     16
```

Good point - in last version of pandas (2.1.4+) need transpose, thank you @nick:

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
df = df.T

out = (pd.concat([df,
                 df.groupby(df.index.to_period('Q')).sum()]).T
          .sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: pd.PeriodIndex(x, 'Q'))
         )


out.columns = [x.strftime("Q%q'%y") 
               if isinstance(x, pd.Period) 
               else x for x in out.columns]

print (out)
```

---

```
       2024-03-01 00:00:00  Q1'24  2024-04-01 00:00:00  2024-05-01 00:00:00  \
part                                                                          
part1                    6      6                    8                    2   
part2                    7      7                    1                    3   
part3                   10     10                    7                    4   
part4                    6      6                    9                    3   
part5                    2      2                    1                   10   
part6                    1      1                    0                    4   

       2024-06-01 00:00:00  Q2'24  2024-07-01 00:00:00  2024-08-01 00:00:00  \
part                                                                          
part1                    3     13                    0                    5   
part2                    8     12                    9                    4   
part3                    5     16                    6                   10   
part4                    0     12                   10                    9   
part5                    8     19                    7                    3   
part6                    1      5                    1                    7   

       2024-09-01 00:00:00  Q3'24  
part                               
part1                    5     10  
part2                   10     23  
part3                    0     16  
part4                   10     29  
part5                    3     13  
part6                    8     16
```

Comment: This code produces a deprecated warning on pandas 2.1.4. That's why I used the transpose in my answer...

Comment: @Nick - I use old version of pandas ;)

Comment: Time to update! :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to transpose the data and use a [`Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) to group quarterly data; then you can convert the index of the resultant data to a `Period` and concat that back to the data, transposing it again to get the desired result:

```
tmp = df.T
tmp.index = pd.to_datetime(tmp.index)
res = tmp.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='Q')).sum()
res.index = res.index.to_period('Q')
out = pd.concat([tmp, res]).sort_index(key=lambda x:pd.PeriodIndex(x, 'Q')).T
```

Output:

```
        2024-03-01 00:00:00  2024Q1  2024-04-01 00:00:00  2024-05-01 00:00:00  \
part
part1                     6       6                    8                    2
part2                     7       7                    1                    3
part3                    10      10                    7                    4
part4                     6       6                    9                    3
part5                     2       2                    1                   10
part6                     1       1                    0                    4

        2024-06-01 00:00:00  2024Q2  2024-07-01 00:00:00  2024-08-01 00:00:00  \
part
part1                     3      13                    0                    5
part2                     8      12                    9                    4
part3                     5      16                    6                   10
part4                     0      12                   10                    9
part5                     8      19                    7                    3
part6                     1       5                    1                    7

        2024-09-01 00:00:00  2024Q3
part
part1                     5      10
part2                    10      23
part3                     0      16
part4                    10      29
part5                     3      13
part6                     8      16
```

Comment: You might be able to sort the index/columns by using the periods as key ;)

Comment: @mozway not sure I've ever seen that done? do you mean with a key function?

Comment: Just add `sort_index(lambda x: pd.PeriodIndex(x, 'Q'))` before transposing.

Comment: Yeah. was trying to just pass a key function, rather than a lambda...

Comment: @jezrael I don't see the point of posting essentially the same answer as Nick's. Especially since grouping on columns is now being deprecated.

Comment: @mozway - It is same? `pd.Grouper(freq='Q')` I dont use

Comment: @mozway - hmm,  `essentially the same answer as Nick's`. If missing some periods, ouput of both answers is different, my answer not create `0` columns

Comment: @jezrael under what conditions do you think my answer will generate 0 columns?

Comment: @Nick - If missing some period between then `Grouper` create column with `0` values, Because ouput of `Grouper` are all consecutive Periods

Comment: @jezrael that's a fair point although probably unlikely to be an issue for OP.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
def get_subtotal(df):
    df.loc[df.index.to_period('Q').strftime("Q%q'%y")[0]] = df.sum()
    return df

df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
out = df.T.resample('Q', group_keys=False).apply(get_subtotal).T
```

out

[image]

If there are discontinuous periods instead of continuous quarters, groupby is safer than resample.

```
out = df.T.groupby(df.columns.to_period('Q'), group_keys=False).apply(get_subtotal).T
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'2024-03-01 00:00:00': {'part1': 6, 'part2': 7, 'part3': 10, 'part4': 6, 'part5': 2, 'part6': 1}, '2024-04-01 00:00:00': {'part1': 8, 'part2': 1, 'part3': 7, 'part4': 9, 'part5': 1, 'part6': 0}, '2024-05-01 00:00:00': {'part1': 2, 'part2': 3, 'part3': 4, 'part4': 3, 'part5': 10, 'part6': 4}, '2024-06-01 00:00:00': {'part1': 3, 'part2': 8, 'part3': 5, 'part4': 0, 'part5': 8, 'part6': 1}, '2024-07-01 00:00:00': {'part1': 0, 'part2': 9, 'part3': 6, 'part4': 10, 'part5': 7, 'part6': 1}, '2024-08-01 00:00:00': {'part1': 5, 'part2': 4, 'part3': 10, 'part4': 9, 'part5': 3, 'part6': 7}, '2024-09-01 00:00:00': {'part1': 5, 'part2': 10, 'part3': 0, 'part4': 10, 'part5': 3, 'part6': 8}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

df:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see code.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data='''
part,"2024-03-01 00:00:00","2024-04-01 00:00:00","2024-05-01 00:00:00","2024-06-01 00:00:00","2024-07-01 00:00:00","2024-08-01 00:00:00","2024-09-01 00:00:00"
part1,6,8,2,3,0,5,5
part2,7,1,3,8,9,4,10
part3,10,7,4,5,6,10,0
part4,6,9,3,0,10,9,10
part5,2,1,10,8,7,3,3
part6,1,0,4,1,1,7,8
'''
data_str=StringIO(data)

df=pd.read_csv(data_str)
print(df)
#Unpivot the DF
un_pivot = pd.melt(df, 
   id_vars = 'part',var_name='date', value_name='count'

)
print(un_pivot.dtypes)
un_pivot['date']=pd.to_datetime(un_pivot['date'])

un_pivot_g=un_pivot.groupby(['part', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='Q')]).sum().reset_index()

un_pivot_g['date'] = un_pivot_g['date'].dt.to_period('Q').astype(str)


pivot_result = un_pivot_g.pivot_table(index='part', columns='date', values='count')

final_df = pd.merge(df, pivot_result, on='part')
print(final_df,'output')
```

Output Image

[image]